# Generating inline javascript with cl-who, parenscript and hunchentoot

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot, cl-who, parenscript

I'm trying to generate inline javascript, but I have to put the parenscript code inside `(:script)` and `(str)` tags using cl-who. `ps`, `ps*`, `ps-inline` and `ps-inline*` don't seem to make much difference to the generated js.

Is the usual way to write a macro to avoid code duplication, or is there a better way?

Here's my program:

```
(in-package #:ps-test)

(defmacro standard-page ((&key title) &body body)
  `(with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output* nil :prologue t :indent t)
     (:html 
      :lang "en"
      (:head 
       (:meta :http-equiv "Content-Type" 
          :content    "text/html;charset=utf-8")
       (:title ,title)
           (:link :type "text/css" 
              :rel "stylesheet"
              :href "/style.css"))
      (:body 
       ,@body))))     

(defun main ()
  (with-html-output (*standard-output* nil :indent t :prologue nil)
    (standard-page (:title "Parenscript test")
      (:div (str "Hello worldzors"))
        (:script :type "text/javascript"
             (str (ps (alert "Hello world as well")))))))

(define-easy-handler (docroot :uri "/") ()
  (main))

(defun start-ps-test ()
  (setf (html-mode) :html5)
  (setf *js-string-delimiter* #\")
  (start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 8080)))

(defun stop-ps-test ()
  (stop *server*))

(defvar *server* (start-ps-test))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are fine in this use case.
The trick is that macros are expanded in a specific order.  Say
you define a `js` macro: when macroexpansion encounters
`with-html-output`, the inner call to your macros `(js (alert "Ho Ho Ho"))` looks like a function call, and is left as-is in the generated
code.  If your `js` macro *then* expands into `(:script ...)`, then the system will complain that `:script` is an unknown function (assuming you
didn't actually name a function like that).  You should emit an
enclosing `(who:htm ...)` expression to interpret the code using
CL-WHO's code walker.

```
(defmacro js (code)
  `(who:htm
     (:script :type "text/javascript" (who:str (ps:ps ,code)))))
```

This only works in the context of an enclosing `with-html-output`.

For inline Javascript, you don't want to have a `<script>` tag around it,
and you can generally simply use `ps-inline`:

```
(who:with-html-output (*standard-output*)
  (:a :href (ps:ps-inline (void 0))
    "A link where the usual HREF behavior is canceled."))

;; prints:
;; 
;; <a href='javascript:void(0)'>A link where the usual HREF behavior is canceled.</a>
```

But feel free to use a macro if you often do the same thing:

```
(defmacro link (&body body)
  `(who:htm (:a :href #.(ps:ps-inline (void 0)) ,@body)))

(who:with-html-output (*standard-output*) (link "Link"))

;; prints:
;;
;; <a href='javascript:void(0)'>Link</a>
```